# Autenteticación basica

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

Necesito realizar una integración con una aplicación pos para consumir inventario.
actualmente la autenticación la estoy realizando de la siguiente forma

```
    <?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

// Conexión WooCommerce API destino Producción.
// ================================
$url_API_woo = 'https://nutrafitcolombia.com/';
$ck_API_woo = 'ck_8d1c05b576c93cbe2bde68ad6ab45739d0351870';
$cs_API_woo = 'cs_586e2f9b6691d2d92bb43c1f61fa85afac2317eb';

$woocommerce = new Client(
    $url_API_woo,
    $ck_API_woo,
    $cs_API_woo,
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3',
        'query_string_auth' => true
    ]
);
```

pero al momento de realizar la prueba me genera este mensaje

https://nutrafitcolombia.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products

```
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Lo siento, no puedes listar recursos.","data":{"status":401}}
```

esta es una integración con wordpress, ya genere las Keys y es las que estan en la información.

com opuedo solucionar este inconveniente

Comment: quiero creer que todas esas claves no son reales no?

Comment: No lo son, es un sitio de prueba

Comment: buenisimo.. solo chequeaba ;)